# Как декодировать cобранный webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

У меня имеется собранный webpack и source map к нему. 
Есть ли возможность на основе моих файлов получить исходные? Если да, то каким образом?

p.s. я мягко говоря новичок в работе с вебпаком.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте например debundle: https://www.npmjs.com/package/debundle